# Regex with lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I can't seem to make this regex work.

The input is as follows. Its really on one row but I have inserted line breaks after each \r\n so that it's easier to see, so no check for space characters are needed.

```
01-03\r\n
01-04\r\n
TEXTONE\r\n
STOCKHOLM\r\n
350,00\r\n            ---- 350,00 should be the last value in the first match
12-29\r\n
01-03\r\n
TEXTTWO\r\n
COPENHAGEN\r\n
10,80\r\n
```

This could go on with another 01-31 and 02-01, marking another new match (these are dates).

I would like to have a total of 2 matches for this input.
My problem is that I cant figure out how to look ahead and match the starting of a new match (two following dates) but not to include those dates within the first match. They should belong to the second match.

It's hard to explain, but I hope someone will get me.
This is what I got so far but its not even close:

```
(.*?)((?<=\\d{2}-\\d{2}))
```

The matches I want are:

```
1: 01-03\r\n01-04\r\nTEXTONE\r\nSTOCKHOLM\r\n350,00\r\n
2: 12-29\r\n01-03\r\nTEXTTWO\r\nCOPENHAGEN\r\n10,80\r\n
```

After that I can easily separate the columns with \r\n.

Comment: Are you saying that your input string contains "backslash r backslash n", and not new line characters? That seems rather strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option for you to try:

```
(.+?)(?=\d{2}-\d{2}\\r\\n\d{2}-\d{2}|$)
```

[Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/9FEvg1G8K1)

Comment: I marked this as answer instead since it doesnt care about the nr of columns or that the last one must be a number like with Rubens regex. This worked 100% with all my test data which had different nr of columns and also strangely formatted currency as the last column :) Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Can this more explicit pattern work to you?

```
(\d{2}-\d{2})\r\n(\d{2}-\d{2})\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(\d+(?:,?\d+))
```

Comment: This regex require exact nr of columns and the last one to be a number. This was correct based on my test data, but Mark's answer was spot on. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

```
/
   \G
   (
      (?:
         [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\r\n
      ){2}
      (?:
         (?! [0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\r\n ) [^\n]*\n
      )*
   )
/xg
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do so much work?

```
$string = q(01-03\r\n01-04\r\nTEXTONE\r\nSTOCKHOLM\r\n350,00\r\n12-29\r\n01-03\r\nTEXTTWO\r\nCOPENHAGEN\r\n10,80\r\n);
for (split /(?=(?:\d{2}-\d{2}\\r\\n){2})/, $string) {
   print join( "\t", split /\\r\\n/), "\n"
}
```

Output:

```
01-03   01-04   TEXTONE STOCKHOLM       350,00
12-29   01-03   TEXTTWO COPENHAGEN      10,80`
```